# Got "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" when I expect JSON

Tags: json, ajax, xml, servlets

I am running a simple website that communicates with a TestServlet using ajax and jquery. The servlet gives a JSON object using doGet(), as follows:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String json = "{\"name\": \"jsontest\",\"type\":\"jsonobject\"}";
    response.getWriter().append(json);
}
```

When a button is pressed on the page, an ajax request is issued as follows:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "test",
 data: "",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(reply) { window.alert("Success\n"+reply); },
 error: function(err) { window.alert(err); }
```

});

The request obtains success, but `reply` is null and I get from web console:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost:8585/web/test
Line Number 1, Column 1: {"name": "jsontest","type":"jsonobject"}
```

I tried to specify `mimeType: "application\json"` but I got the same behavior. Instead, when I don't specify `dataType` or I put `contentType: "json"` I succeed to read correctly the JSON string but still I get the `XML Parsing Error`.

**Can anyone explain why I get a XML Parsing Error while I am supposing to exchange JSON?**

NOTE: I'm using Firefox and Tomcat9.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, I found out that while I was expecting json content in the request through `dataType`, the servlet was not specifying that its response was coded with that type too.
Adding:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks to [@Gabriele Ara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7030275/gabriele-ara) for suggestions.